# Is companion always instance of the class?

Tags: scala, singleton

I read [the article](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html) about singleton objects in scala but didn't find abything about if it's an instance of the class.
The following simple program tells that for this particular case it's true:

```
class TestMatch(val i: Int)

object TestMatch{
  def apply(i: Int) = new TestMatch(i)
  def unapply(tm : TestMatch): Option[Int] = Some(tm.i)
}
```

I tried to test it as this:

```
println(TestMatch.isInstanceOf[TestMatch]) //false
```

but it generated the warning `fruitless type test`.
I'm not sure how to perform such test.

Comment: Not sure what you're proving here - if you remove the object entirely you'd still get the same result - `tm` is an instance of the class `TestMatch`, none of these refer to the `TestMatch` companion object.

Comment: @TzachZohar Yes, I just noticed that. But what about the original question. What is the type of companion object?

Comment: @TzachZohar I just edited my question

Comment: The type of `object TestMatch` is `TestMatch$`. You can check it with `TestMatch.getClass`. **It is not an instance of class `TestMatch`**! But you can make it by extending it, of course...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`object`s are always an instance of an anonymous class whose body is the `object` definition's body. If the definition does not include an `extends` clause, that class inherits directly from `AnyRef`.

So the only way the `TestMatch` object could be an instance of the `TestMatch` class would be if you wrote `object TestMatch extends TestMatch(something) {...}`. Since you didn't do that, the `TestMatch` is not an instance of `TestMatch` in your code.

PS: The reason you're getting that warning for your test code is that Scala already knows at compile time exactly what the type of `TestMatch` is, so it knows that the run-time test can only ever result in `false` and is thus "fruitless". Generally you'd use run-time type tests when the exact type of something is not determined until run time and the test may thus may be true or false.

Comment: Nitpick: from `AnyRef`, not from `Any`.